# javascript setTimeout not activating

Tags: jquery, json, settimeout

When i'm using this code it's not activating the setTimeout on success return from jQuery

```
function waitForEvents(last_id){
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/functions/ajax.php?func=feed&old_msg_id="+last_id,

            async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
            cache: false,
            timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

            success: function(data){
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if(json !== 'null') {
                $.each(json.earnings, function (index, value) {
                     $('#feed').append(value);
                });
                var old_msg_id = json['last_id'];
                }
                alert("working");
                setTimeout('waitForEvents(last_id)',"1000");  
            },

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("Error:" + textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                setTimeout('waitForEvents(last_id)',"15000");       
            },
});
};
```

Any idea why because it's actually returning (data) so it's processing the response just not activating the settimeout again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setTimeout method is not passing a function (apparently as a string is fine :/)

```
setTimeout(function() { waitForEvents(last_id); }, 15000);
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why it's not working. You *can* pass a string into `setTimeout` (you shouldn't, but you can).

Comment: When using this it doesn't even process the jQuery call for some reason

Comment: Apologies I did not know that. But can you pass the code like that? It's still not wrapped in a function, which should be needed to pass the parameter?

Comment: @CurtisCrewe this should work just fine. Check the browser's error console, what you see?

Comment: @ShadowWizard it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'earnings' of null `

Comment: @CurtisCrewe: That would be an unrelated problem.

Comment: if(json !== 'null'), remove the quotes around null

Comment: @CurtisCrewe you didn't copy something properly, you passed wrong ID hence got null json back. Your check is wrong, null value is NOT a "null" string.

Answer (score 0):

The string you pass into `setTimeout` is evaluated at *global* scope. My guess is that either your function is not defined at global scope, or that there is no `last_id` value defined at global scope.

If your goal is to reuse the `last_id` argument that was passed to the function, thenchange your `setTimeout` call to:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    waitForEvents(last_id);
}, 1000); // Or 15000 for the other call
```

(Also note that the second argument should be a *number*, not a string.)

Here's an example of what I mean by the string being evaluated at global scope:

```
(function($) {

  $("#target").click(function() {
    setTimeout(foo, 500);
    setTimeout("bar()", 500);
    display("Timers started");
  });

  function foo() {
    display("foo called");
  }

  function bar() {
    display("bar called");
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
  }

})(jQuery);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/afudus/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/afudus/1/edit)

Assuming you have an element with the `id` `"target"` and you click it, after half a second you'll see "foo called" appear on the page, but you won't see "bar called". If you're using any modern browser, you'll see an error message in the JavaScript console saying that `bar` is undefined. That's because there is no **global** function called `bar`, there's only a function within the wrapper function called `bar`. So the string version fails.

Avoid passing strings to `setTimeout` whenever possible. It is always possible. *(Apologies to the Dalai Lama.)*